# Computing sums and double sums

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I would like to check if my answer is correct:

1) Compute $$\sum_{i=1}^n(3i+4)$$. I got $(3n^2 + 11n) / 2$ using the property that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$

2) I'm unsure how to approach double summations like this: $$\sum_{x = 1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n(x+y−1)$$. Please help explain and the correct answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could checkmark both!

Comment: The second question is especially interesting. See my solution which exploits the symmetry and doesn't require expansion and substitution of standard formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You got that right.

2) Do the sum for $y=1$ to $n$ as if $x$ is a constant. Then sum the result over the values of $x$

$\sum_{y=1}^n(x+y−1)= \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}+n(x-1)= \dfrac {n(n+1)-2n}{2}+nx=\dfrac {n(n-1)}{2}+nx$

$\sum_{x = 1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n(x+y−1)=\dfrac {n^2(n-1)}{2}+n \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}=n^3$

Comment: Where did the -1 go in the second step? Why isn't the final answer n^3 - 1?

Comment: @Ashley - the n(x - 1) term is distributed, resulting in nx and the -2n/2 in the fraction.

Answer (score 5):

1) Looks fine to me.

2) Notice this:

$$\begin{array}{}\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n(x+y-1)&\displaystyle\vphantom{\cfrac11}=\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^nx&\displaystyle+\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^ny&\displaystyle-\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n1\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}&\displaystyle=\sum_{x=1}^nx\sum_{y=1}^n1&\displaystyle+\sum_{x=1}^n1\sum_{y=1}^ny&\displaystyle-\sum_{x=1}^n1\sum_{y=1}^n1\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}&\displaystyle=\frac{n(n+1)}2\cdot n&\displaystyle+n\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2&\displaystyle-n\cdot n\\&=n^3\end{array}$$

Comment: Hm, I wonder why a downvote :-(

Answer (score 5):

**Second question**

*(Updated solution)*

This can be considered a $2$-D version of the Gaussian pairing technique for summation:

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n (x+y-1)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{s=1}^n (2n-r-s+1)
&&\scriptsize(r=n+1-x, s=n+1-y)\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n (2n-x-y+1)
&&\scriptsize\text{(replacing indices $r,s$ with $x,y$)}\\
2S
&=\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n (x+y-1)+(2n-x-y+1)\\
&=2\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n n\\
S&=\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n n\\
&=\color{red}{n^3}
\end{align}$$

---

For illustration, if $n=5$,

$$\scriptsize\begin{align}
2\times
\boxed{\begin{array}
&1&2&3&4&5\\
2&3&4&5&6\\
3&4&5&6&7\\
4&5&6&7&8\\
5&6&7&8&9
\end{array}}
&=
\boxed{\begin{array}
&1&2&3&4&5\\
2&3&4&5&6\\
3&4&5&6&7\\
4&5&6&7&8\\
5&6&7&8&9
\end{array}}
+\boxed{\begin{array}
&1&2&3&4&5\\
2&3&4&5&6\\
3&4&5&6&7\\
4&5&6&7&8\\
5&6&7&8&9
\end{array}}\\
&=\boxed{\begin{array}
&1&2&3&4&5\\
2&3&4&5&6\\
3&4&5&6&7\\
4&5&6&7&8\\
5&6&7&8&9
\end{array}}+
\boxed{\begin{array}
&9&8&7&6&5\\
8&7&6&5&4\\
7&6&5&4&3\\
6&5&4&3&2\\
5&4&3&2&1
\end{array}}\\
&=\boxed{\begin{array}
&10&10&10&10&10\\
10&10&10&10&10\\
10&10&10&10&10\\
10&10&10&10&10\\
10&10&10&10&10\\
\end{array}}\\
\boxed{\begin{array}
&1&2&3&4&5\\
2&3&4&5&6\\
3&4&5&6&7\\
4&5&6&7&8\\
5&6&7&8&9
\end{array}}
&=
\boxed{\begin{array}
&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5\\
\end{array}}\\
&=5^3\end{align}$$
($x$ horizontal L to R, $y$ vertical down, numbers in box are $x+y-1$ and are to be summed)

Comment: Wow. Beautiful method and nice visualization!

Comment: @AliasUser - Hey thanks! Very kind of you to say so. Glad you like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

A few tricks:

1. the sum of the terms is always the product of the number of terms and the average value of the terms,
2. the average value of a constant term is that constant,
3. the average value of a linear term is the mean of the extreme values.

Then by 1. and 3.,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(3i+4)=n\frac{3+4+3n+4}2.$$

For the other sum, you can decompose in three double sums, on $x$, $y$ and $-1$.

Then by 1., 2. and 3.,

$$\sum_{x = 1}^n\sum_{y=1}^n(x+y−1)=2n\frac{n^2+n}2-n^2.$$

---

Justification:

In the double sum of $x$, the $x$ is a constant for the inner sum, which then equals $nx$. The outer sum yields

$$n\frac{n^2+n}2.$$

By symmetry, the sum on $y$ equals that on $x$, hence the factor $2$.